# new web site on windows 2008 server with IIS7 - does not work

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have a new domain: www.biografica.ro which was bought 3 months ago but never used still then.

I've bought a server with Windows 2008 server instaWeb Server (IIS).

I've added a new site in C:\inetpu\wwwroot directory and did the setting (assigned the default ip to www.biografica.ro host etc -i've did on IIS6 one year ago, so i think i know to set up it correctly)...

The problem is that the default site created by IIS instalation is working, but mine is not.
It is started but is says: *This link appears to be broken* in Chrome and "The webpage cannot be found" (in IE).

Do you know guys what i;ve done wrong?

As i know a domain takes time to propagate but i think locally it should work..

Please help...i've spent 3 hours and cannot find a way...:(

SOLVED: asp.net websites must be converted to application not use as static web sites:)

Answer (score 0):

- DOES the name propagate? basically use any of the ping tools on the internet or your local one to find out where the domain ends (the ip address).
- Is the server reachable? As in: not behind NAT etc.?

Comment: Yes, the server ip can be reached from my machine. ...It should at least show me the web site, locally..but it does not.